# Spawn external process from a CGI script

Tags: perl, apache2, cgi

I've searched and found several very similar questions to mine but nothing in those answers have worked for me yet.

I have a perl CGI script that accepts a file upload.  It looks at the file and determines how it should be processed and then calls a second non-CGI script to do the actual processing.  At least, that's how it *should* work.

This is running on Windows with Apache 2.0.59 and ActiveState Perl 5.8.8.  The file uploading part works fine but I can't seem to get the *`upload.cgi`* script to run the second script that does the actual processing.  The second script doesn't communicate in any way with the user that sent the file (other than it sends an email when it's done).  I want the CGI script to run the second script (in a separate process) and then 'go away'.

So far I've tried `exec`, system (passing a 1 as the first parameter), system (without using 1 as first parameter and calling '*`start`*'), and Win32::Process.  Using system with 1 as the first parameter gave me errors in the Apache log:

> *'1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r, referer: http://my.server.com/cgi-bin/upload.cgi*

Nothing else has given me any errors but they just don't seem to work.  The second script logs a message to the Windows event log as one of the first things it does.  No log entry is being created.

It works fine on my local machine under Omni webserver but not on the actual server machine running Apache.  Is there an Apache config that could be affecting this?  The *`upload.cgi`* script resides in the *`d:\wwwroot\test\cgi-bin`* dir but the other script is elsewhere on the same machine (*`d:\wwwroot\scripts`*).

Comment: Why are you passing a 1 to `system`?

Comment: @friedo, Windows-specific extension to `system` that makes `system` not wait.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a security related problem, but it should be apparent in the logs. 
This won't exactly answer your question but it may give you other implementation ideas where you will not face with potential security and performance problems.

I don't quite like mixing my web server environment with system() calls. Instead, I create an application server (with [POE](http://search.cpan.org/~rcaputo/POE-1.354/lib/POE.pm) usually) which accepts the relevant parameters from the  web server, processes the job, and notifies the web server upon completion. (well, the notification part may not be straightforward but that's another topic.)